# Invalid username and password on login, CakePHP 2.5.5

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication

I'm using Cakephp version 2.5.5

My problem is I can't log in , $this->Auth->login() always returns false!

What could be wrong? I spent a whole day to checking the code , but no idea ..

I'll appreciate it if you have time to check the code here: https://gist.github.com/ansidev/953653464899835fff4c

Everything included : User.php , UsersController.php , login.ctp , register.ctp

Thanks in advance ...

Comment: What error message are you getting in logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make this changes -

in `AppController.php`

```
'passwordHasher' => 'Blowfish',
'fields'         => array(
                     'username' => 'user_login',
                     'password' => 'user_pass',
                    ),
```

Assuming that - `user_login` would be the field name for username and `user_pass` would be the field for password. Hope it will help you.